# Most optimised way to do dom manipulation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

What's the most reliable / optimised way in React for animating a dom element with a number sequence going from 0 to N, using a tween library? I assume using setState would not be ideal, even if you use it with `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

Is references the most reliable option?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I think the better choice is using a library [react motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion)

Comment: while I understand that libraries like react motion might come in handy for simplification, my question is more focused on optimisation on the 'react' side of things in particular accessing a reference vs going through the lifecycle. But fair enough I did use the word reliable but I meant fastest.

Comment: I don't think that there is another legal way to impact DOM changes than `setState` and manage stability, performance, reliability, and other familiar stuff is definitely your responsibility, `react` just provide for you a couple different ways to do that.

Comment: For example, for more safe usage `ref`, I can recommend using `React.createRef()` instead of just bind `ref` prop, but if you'd like to have advantages wich `react` is providing for `DOM` manipulation, so use `setState` in pairs of lifecycle methods to have more control, also take a look at `React.PureComponent `, and move all your tween logic to the separate component which will be a wrapper for animation.

Comment: You see that there a lot of stuff to keep at mind and my opinion is the same as above - library, cuz life is to short to reinvent a bike)

Comment: And finally, in the documentation it says that use Refs for **triggering** imperative animations

Comment: Replying to your first comment, my question is aimed towards animation and performance. calling setState 60FPS is never a good idea. But I accept your other reply recommending React.createRef() instead of having the method inline. :)

Comment: Bit of a vague question. Get initial refs using React, and then abstract animation behaviour far away from React and use a perf-optimised JS animation library, or trigger CSS animations if that is suitable. Don't understand these attempts at forcing unsuitable things into React just cuz.

Comment: I am not sure that `setState` reduce performance. A re-rendering of a big and nested `DOM` tree might be impacting FPS of UI, but it it's more related to how the app is designed but not event directly to `setState`, cuz it just a trigger of what can be heavy operation. [simple example of something that can look like what about we discussing](https://codesandbox.io/s/23y0y9mp20)

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that calling setState will impact the performance on the page as there's a lot behind the scenes happening on each setState. I mean there's a reason React API delivers the a `reference` as part of the API. With setState, as you pointed out correctly, the virtual dom gets destroyed and re-created. On my particular question, using a reference is the most performant solution.

Comment: Lastly, on your example you will never be able to run that interval every 10ms because your browser refresh rate is most likely 60Hz which means you can render 60 frames a seconds, which means 1000ms divided by 60frames ≃ 16ms so any value less that 16 in the setInterval is just going to be unnecessary.

Comment: Also, you should use the requestAnimationFrame API instead of using a setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we're using gsap to animate our div, a solution could be something like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { TweenLite, Power2 } from 'gsap';

class Example extends PureComponent {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.dummy = {
            value: 0
        };

        TweenLite.to(this.dummy, 0.8, {
            value: 100,
            ease: Power2.easeInOut,
            onUpdate: () => {
                this.domElement.innerHTML = this.dummy.value;
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        TweenLite.killTweensOf(this.dummy);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={(dom) => { this.domElement = dom; }} />
        );
    }
}
```